# txt file or JDOM or DOM or

Tags: java, dom, jdom, jaxp

I want to save some data with Java but I don't want to use Database ( MySQL, ... ).
The program's attribute will be saved in a file and updated 500 times per second and loaded one time when the program will be executed. This program may be running for 5 hours or more. performance (speed) in this program is prominent.

---

Thank you for your answers. I can't use RAM because if my PC shutdown Unexpectedly(for example power cable unplugged) I lose my information. I save/update one Long-variable, 500/1024 times per sec.

Comment: may I know what you have tried up to now?

Comment: Which one do I use.(JDOM or DOM or JAXP or .txt file or litgh database).this program's platform is Linux.

Comment: it'd better you use in memory database for better performance. [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-memory_database) you can find number of in memory databases. Dont use Mysql, it is slow in performance on updates.

Comment: Is it not an option to save the data in the program until just  before the program is terminated, and then write it to the file? What amounts of data are we talking about?

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure about the performance suitability (though I imagine it will be fine), but Java has java.util.prefs.Preferences which is designed to do this sort of storage. You should at least consider it.

You should also consider java.util.Properties, which can easily do that too, even as XML....

JDOM itself (which I maintain, and thus have some bias) would be capable of it, depending on the size of the file, and your hardware, and whether you re-format the data when you output it (or use the faster/default 'raw' format).

The real question is "What is your question?" ....

- can it be done?
- can it be done with JDOM?
- can it be done with DOM?
- can it be done better with something else?
- can it be done faster on Linux than Windows (which I imagine is true...)
- why save it 500 times a second at all? Why not cache it and load a [shutdown hook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29) to save?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe consider [google protocol buffer](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) to store your settings. Apparently they can be parsed/written very fast. If you want to enjoy the speed of it however, it will not be stored in a human readable format. I can not conclude from your question however that you want that.

Basically protocol buffers will allow you to define what you want to store and then generate the code to actually save/load that data. Because it writes in binary it can be faster than XML or typical jave Properties files. So if performance is really crucial you should definatly consider this.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you're looking for, but have you thought about [Object Serialization](http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/articles/serialization/index.html)? Basically, you have your objects implament `java.io.Serializable` and then you can give them to an [`ObjectOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) and say `out.writeObject(yourObject)`. It's super easy. Here's an example method from the [Java Helper Library](https://github.com/kentcdodds/Java-Helper) for writing and reading.

```
/**
* Saves the given object to the given destination. The object and all it's variables must implement
* java.io.Serializable or the variables must have the keyword "transient" in front of it.
*
* @param object
* @param savePath
* @throws IOException
*/
public static void saveObject(Object object, String savePath) throws IOException {
  FileOutputStream f_out = new FileOutputStream(savePath); //If you want the object to be saved in memory just create a ByteArrayOutputStream instead and return the bytes in this method.
  ObjectOutputStream o_out = new ObjectOutputStream(f_out);
  o_out.writeObject(object);
}

/**
* Opens an object from the given openPath and returns it
*
* @param openPath
* @return
* @throws IOException
* @throws ClassNotFoundException
*/
public static Object loadObject(String openPath) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
  FileInputStream f_in = new FileInputStream(openPath); //If you want the object to be saved in memory just give the method a byte[] and create a ByteArrayInputStream instead.
  ObjectInputStream o_in = new ObjectInputStream(f_in);
  return o_in.readObject();
}
```